# Registration with LDAP authentication on Rocketchat

Tags: ldap, registration, openldap, rocket.chat

I have a Rocketchat server on docker and have Openldap server on ubuntu 16.04. I want when any user registered in my Rocketchat server by default to be added to his ldap server automatically.
is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You probably would get it easier the other way, register the user in LDAP and then sync LDAP with RocketChat.

This way you can use LDAP Sync to get your RocketChat users synced.